# Can embedded webpages change the code of the main page?

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I have created a webpage that has an embedded webpage in itself. Can this embedded page execute functions on the main page, such as `innerHTML()`?

Comment: Depends on how you embedded it and where from.

Comment: @Quentin I embedded it using iframe

Comment: Depends on how you embedded it **and where from**

Comment: @Quentin I embedded it from an HTML file in the project folder

Comment: So not a different origin then

Comment: @Quentin yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the window object of the parent document through the [`parent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent).